# How do I put a png-24 as a background in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I tried to upload a png image that I made in photoshop cc2015 as a background image in my project on android studio but the app produced by that crashed with no messages of any errors.

Comment: At first, try to emulate the problem with a small image. If it runs, big pic is exploding your memory. If the problem persists, try a png-8, or a jpg image, a small one first, and see what happens.

Comment: I tried and it worked with the other images except the images from the photoshop

Comment: Maybe it's the algorithm Photoshop uses to save, or compress or the interlace option. Try by the ´save as´ option, verify whether PS has options for this (interlace etc). If none of this works, use an alternative soft to export your png24 files, there are many options, including online tools.

Comment: Hi I tried to import with 'save as' but all the options failed. What alternative soft can I export my png24 files? I need help quickly!!!

Comment: I tried to export***

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to use your image as a JPG and then apply a transparency on it, like this:

```
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.artboard);
    iv.setAlpha(0.2f);
```

This code understand that you named your ImageView (inside XML) as "iv1", and your jpg, inside drawables folder, "artboard".

The value showed here as "0.2f" is a float value. You can change it freely to tune up the alpha.

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work. I tried to put this code in fragment but the app crashed again and again without an error message